# My application is crashed after i configure in other pc

Tags: android, eclipse

When i configure my app in other computer,app is crashed.check my log-cat.I have also added 
android-v4-support.jar.

> 04-26 11:39:54.695: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable start     activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.rockers.airtasker/com.rockers.airtasker.ProjectHome}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: share the xml layout you have as the content view of your ```ProjectHome``` activity. The logcat says the problem is with it in its 19th line.

Comment: please check i have added xml file

Comment: Finally spending a half day have solved it. I have added the andoid-v13-support.jar for navigation drawer and forgot to check it in order and export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the newest version of it? v4 support libary is famous to cause problems if used in wrong version/dependency.